# "<?php" at Beginning of File Makes it Unreadable by Owner

Tags: permissions, rhel

I have a situation I've never seen before and haven't been able to find in my searching. I have a PHP file that is not viewable or editable by the owner or any group owner. Oddly, Apache *can* read and process the file, so it's not corrupt as far as I can tell. Also, it can be viewed and edited with `sudo` (i.e. as root).

What I've discovered is that any file that has `<?php` on the first line (which is pretty common for PHP files) exhibits this behavior. I just tested this in my home directory:

```
$ vi henry.txt
```

I put some text in it and save it. No problem. I can view the file:

```
$ cat henry.txt
Test
```

I edit the file again (`vi henry.txt`) and put `<?php` on the first line, pushing `Test` down to the second line. Then I save and exit. Now:

```
$ cat henry.txt
cat: henry.txt: Operation not permitted
```

but:

```
$ sudo cat henry.txt
<?php
Test
```

I edit the file again (`sudo vi henry.txt` because I can't edit it as myself) and remove the `<?php` line. Save and exit. Now:

```
$ cat henry.txt
Test
```

In fact, I don't even need the full `<?php` to block access. Simply putting `<?` there will do it.

I'm totally at a loss as to why this might be. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. In case it matters, this is Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8. I've tried disabling SELinux but that made no difference.

EDIT: More console output, showing file ownership (me) and permissions. The behavior is identical in my home directory and in /tmp.

```
[hartley_h@webnix07 ~]$ cd /tmp
[hartley_h@webnix07 tmp]$ echo "Test" > henry.txt
[hartley_h@webnix07 tmp]$ ls -l henry.txt
-rw-r-----. 1 hartley_h domain users 5 Oct 29 15:44 henry.txt
[hartley_h@webnix07 tmp]$ cat henry.txt
Test
[hartley_h@webnix07 tmp]$ echo "<?php" > henry.txt
[hartley_h@webnix07 tmp]$ ls -l henry.txt
-rw-r-----. 1 hartley_h domain users 6 Oct 29 15:45 henry.txt
[hartley_h@webnix07 tmp]$ cat henry.txt
cat: henry.txt: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: When reproducing this, can you post the output of `ls -l henry.txt` at each step?

Comment: When working as the root user, permissions are basically ignored, so it's quite natural that it can be read an written by root.

Comment: “Operation not permitted” means a restriction that is not due to permissions (restrictions due to permissions would result in “Permission denied” instead). This could be due to a security module but I'm not aware of a security module that inspects file contents. What filesystem is the file on? Do you see the same effect with a file in `/tmp` or in `/var/tmp`?

Comment: You should include the directory listings as you did on your [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69709360/why-can-i-only-view-edit-one-of-these-files-although-they-have-identical-permiss?noredirect=1#comment123327395_69709360).

Comment: A very long post about permissions but you never show us the permissions nor the ownership. Your assertion that `<?php` changes the access is highly dubious but you provide no details of how you arrived at this conclusion.

Comment: Is one of $USER's `vi` plugins trying to do something (syntax highlighting, tab setting, etc) based on `<?php`, and choking because the file is malformed at the moment? Read `man vi` and start editing without plugins, or use a different editor (see `man -k editor`).

Comment: I've added more console output, creating the file without vi, showing file permissions, and doing it in the /tmp directory. Also, the file system is xfs.

Comment: Are you in a container? I found a topic suggesting passing `--privileged` to `docker`.

Comment: No, not a container.

Comment: The output you've added now shoes clearly that this is not about permissions. But as @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' said, the error message also shows something else is going on. Probably some kind of security module, I know of some, but nothing usable. You need to talk to whoever set up the machine.